# ZF2 form formatting?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 and have a form which defines a bunch of elements, and then I render it in my phtml like this:

```
<?php 

$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formlabel($form->get('description'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('radioButton'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();

?>
```

Which draws a label and a radio button.
My question is how can I then format these elements to my liking? For example make the radio buttons displayed horizontally rather than vertically and maybe change the location of the label.

Comment: The default view helpers render the way you are seeing it in your output: either render them manually (by interacting with the form element properties in your view) or create new view helpers aligned to your needs

Comment: In addition to what @Ocramius said, the syntax of your said helper is: `formRow($element, $position, $renderErrors)`. You could do this: `$this->formRow($element, 'prepend')` to have Checkboxes be prepended with the label.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from formatting them as you have there, you could put the elements inside a list, or andd any additional markup you want to style as you wish.

```
<?php 
$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
?>
<ul class="form-list">
    <li>
    <div class="form-control">
        <?php echo $this->formlabel($form->get('description')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('description')) ?>
        <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('description')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <?php echo $this->formlabel($form->get('radioButton')); ?>
        <?php echo $this->formElementErrors($form->get('radioButton')) ?>
        <?php echo $this->formElement($form->get('radioButton')); ?>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>
```

If you wanted to have control over the actual elements/inputs themselves you could do something like this:

```
<label>
    <?php echo $form->get('radioButton')->getLabel() ?>
    <input class="bob" type="radio" 
           name="<?php echo $form->get('radioButton')->getName() ?>"
           value="<?php echo $form->get('radioButton')->getValue() ?>"
    />
</label>
```